# Creating Websites in C# Bad Idea?

Tags: c#, .net, web-deployment

Is it a good idea to create a website using C# and .Net? I thought of using PHP and codeignator but I would have to learn two new things.

1. **Is it possible to do this fully in C#?**
2. Could I do it completely inside Visual Studio?
3. **What kind of problems should I expect?**
4. Is it a good idea or should I be looking at PHP and Phython (the only opinionated part so please use your own experience as example to prove this point).

The **bold** points are the ones I care most about. I understand #4 is very opinionated but if you can provide me with your own experience it would help, something like "I tried and my website was really slow/fast because of [this]." would help.

Comment: I'm afraid your whole question is opinion based (except 1/2, but there is not enough content to be accepted as valid SO answer).  1 - yes, 2 - yes, 3 - yes, of all kinds, 4 - yes, and you should be looking at other things to learn too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's a good idea.
The entire StackExchange network is developed in .Net

1. yes
2. yes
3. A lot, performance, hosting, responsiveness, scalabilty.
4. It's possible, of course. I prefer .Net.

Comment: +1. 3: localization, globalization, address space fragmentation,... (maybe someone turns it into haiku or something like that to make it more entertaining).

Comment: When you say performance and responsiveness problems. Do you mean that C# will give me more performance troubles vs PHP? Or overall are you letting me know that websites have those issues?

Comment: @user3555302 i mean overall.